# How to declare Class Instance Variable in inherited class automatically

Tags: ruby, inheritance, class-instance-variables

I am using Class Inheritance Variables in Ruby to keep track of the number of instances I've created so far. To keep my code DRY, I implemented most of the logic in a base class that all my other classes inherit from.

```
class Entity
  @instance_counter = 0

  class << self
    attr_accessor :instance_counter
  end

  def initialize
    self.class.instance_counter += 1
  end
end
```

This works perfectly fine except for one thing:

I have to define `@instance_counter` in each child class, or I will get an `NoMethodError`.

```
class Child < Entity
  @instance_counter = 0
end
```

Is there a way to declare the variable in each child automatically so that I don't have to do it manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best way, but here is how I might do it:

```
class Entity
  singleton_class.send(:attr_writer, :instance_counter)
  def self.instance_counter; @instance_counter ||= 0; end
  def initialize
    self.class.instance_counter += 1
  end
end
```

Comment: is the `singleton_class.send` really needed here?

Comment: It's just an alternative to opening the `singleton_class` as in the question example. I would prefer it e.g. in this case, when I'm only doing one call in that context, but I think it's a matter of personal preference. The `send` is required because `attr_writer` is a private method.

Comment: Thanks @kardeiz! That works and was way too easy. Feels like my Ruby is getting a little rusty.